# Exclude some compile dependencies for runtime in Gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am using Gradle to build my Groovy application. As usual I specify the `compile` dependencies in the `build.gradle` script, like this:

```
dependencies {
    // groovy
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:$groovyVersion"
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:$groovyVersion"
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-test:$groovyVersion"

    // some more external dependencies...
}
```

Ok, for `runtime` I don't need all of these dependencies, for example I don't need any testing classes. So what I am looking for now is a way to tell Gradle that it should use the same dependencies for `runtime` as for `compile` (which is the default anyway), but excluding some of them.

Is there a short way to achieve that, or do I have to list all dependencies for `runtime` as well?

Comment: If you have dependencies that are only relevant for tests, then that's what the `testCompile` configuration is for.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: True, but there are some others as well. For example, Groovy pulls in `asm` as transitive dependency for compilation, but I assume that is not needed at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around: Groovy's transitive dependencies aren't normally required for compilation (except that due to a known limitation of the Groovy compiler, they sometimes *are*), but they are definitely needed at runtime. However, it's not worthwhile to optimize compile dependencies here, so just keep declaring Groovy dependencies as `compile` dependencies (which automatically makes them `runtime` dependencies as well). Groovy test dependencies should be added to the `testCompile` configuration.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the Groovy compiler limitation?

Comment: It uses standard Java reflection to learn about the classes on the compile class path, and that will sometimes fail if classes referenced by those classes aren't on the compile class path.

Comment: So does that mean for example that `asm` is required for runtime, but not compilation?!

Comment: `asm` is necessary to run the compiler, and also to run your Groovy code (definitely in some cases, probably in all). It isn't necessary on the compile class path when compiling your Groovy code (except perhaps due to the Groovy compiler limitation I mentioned). Unless you have a very concrete reason to try and optimize here, don't.